# how to clear my all ng-model old data in button click?

Tags: function, button, angularjs-ng-repeat, rootscope

i have button click clear all ng-model data   (home.html)

```
<button class="btn hvr-underline-from-center" ng-click="clear_data11()">
    <span class="icon-plus"></span> {{x.DryerId}}-{{x.formula_id}} 
 </button>
```

clear funcation (main_controller.js)

```
$rootScope.clear_data11 = function (){$rootScope.MinTemp = "";$rootScope.MaxTemp = "";$rootScope.ActualTemp = "";$rootScope.IsPullPoint ="";$rootScope.ObservedTemp = "";$rootScope.ChemicalManually=""; $rootScope.note = "";}
```